# Populating across multiple levels "Edge case?"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

im newbie, please help me

i have this table:

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      orderId: { type: String, required: true },
      orderItems: [
        {
          quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
          productDetails: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "ProductDetails",
            required: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    }
```

why i can't join productDetails with field orderItems like that:

```
const order = await Order.findOne({ _id: orderId }).populate({
                path: 'orderItems',
                populate: { path: 'productDetails' }
            });
```

I also tried this but it didn't work:

```
const order = await Order.findOne({ _id: orderId }).populate({ path: "orderItems.productDetails", model: "ProductDetails" });
```

and

```
const order = await Order.findOne({ _id: orderId }).populate("orderItems.productDetails");
```

the response is:

```
"data": {
        "_id": "657b6fd4fe166ce7cffcc525",
        "orderId": "gu4Yzp4u",
        "orderItems": [
            {
                "quantity": 5,
                "productDetails": null,
                "_id": "657b6fd4fe166ce7cffcc526"
            },
            {
                "quantity": 5,
                "productDetails": null,
                "_id": "657b6fd4fe166ce7cffcc527"
            },
            {
                "quantity": 1,
                "productDetails": null,
                "_id": "657b6fd4fe166ce7cffcc528"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PENDING",
        "paymentMethod": "COD",
        "description": "hello",
        "customer": "657b6fd4fe166ce7cffcc523",
        "createdAt": "2023-12-14T21:12:52.509Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

I think my issue is because orderItems is an array with two properties: quantity and productDetails